# Three.js transparency model texture bug

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I have searched over all internet and tried a lot of ways, but no results..
How to remove texture transparency bug? Check on image

[image: tree model texture bug]

So, on 3dsmax model looks okey. I have converted to .js format from .obj with python script in order .png files were transparent (.obj does not make transparence).

How to solve my problem? Thank you

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('tree_model.js', function(geometry, materials) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if ( child.material instanceof THREE.MeshPhongMaterial ) {

                // this code is unattainable, but anyway without if (..) it does not work

                child.material.alphaTest = 0.5;
                child.material.depthWrite = false;
                child.material.depthTest = false;
                child.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
                child.material.transparent = true;
            }
        });
        scene.add(object);
    });
});
```

And renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true, premultipliedAlpha: true });
```

Comment: you are using jpg textures that do not hold transparency. convert them to png and only use the `alphaTest`.

Comment: I changed, no results :(

Comment: @gaitat: This model uses Alpha maps to handle transparency, so it could work. In this case it doesnt work because various other code errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set `alphaTest` on your materials. Additionally setting the leafes and branches to `THREE.DoubleSide` ensures that they are not disappearing when viewed from the other side.

The code you have posted contains various errors, so replace it with this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('model/Elka.js', function(geometry, materials) {

    for( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ ) {
        var material = materials[ i ];
        material.alphaTest = 0.5;
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        // not-so-good practice
        if ( material.name === "NorwaySpruceBark" ) {
            material.transparent = false;
        }
    }

    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);
    var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(object);
});
```

To further reduce transparency artefacts, set the trunk to non-transparent. Your model should contain the correct material settings, so this is kind of a bad practice.

**Edit:** Setting `alpha` and `premultipliedAlpha` in the `renderer` is not necessary for this problem.

Result:

[image: Transparent Tree]